# How to make Backbones toJSON function include sub-models and collections?

Tags: backbone.js

I have a few models that don't just contain basic data attributes, but they might have one or two attributes that hold another models object.

This has been okay, but now I want to call

myRootModel.toJSON()

and I've noticed that it doesn't call .toJSON on the other models in my model that I'm trying to call toJSON() on.

Is there a way to override backbone model .toJSON to go through all fields, **recursively**, whether they are basic attributes, sub-models or collections? If not, can I override toJSON in each model / collection?

I'm aware of backbone-relational, but I don't want to go that route - I'm not using fetch/save, instead our API returns responses that I adjust in the models parse function and simply invoke new MyRootModel(data,{parse:true}).

Comment: So you're not actually converting anything to JSON (i.e. a string), you're just using `toJSON` to serialize your data to plain objects and arrays?

Comment: I am indeed using toJSON get get plain objects and arrays, primarily so that BackBone view templates can iterate over them successfully without complications; using underscore templates I can invoke methods on my methods and collections but the advice from a recent London BackBone Meetup was not always convert to plain object (graphs) first.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a way you can achieve such a thing (there's maybe another way):

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.toJSON = function() {
  var json = _.clone(this.attributes);
  for(var attr in json) {
    if((json[attr] instanceof Backbone.Model) || (json[attr] instanceof Backbone.Collection)) {
      json[attr] = json[attr].toJSON();   
    }
  }
  return json;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2Asjc/.

Comment: This seems to be doing the trick, thank you - I'm glad that I didn't over complicate anything with using the backbone-relational approach when this appears to be working well enough for my current needs.

Comment: AFAIK `toJSON` isn't recursive because `JSON.stringify` will [call `toJSON` on its own](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior) as it walks the data structure. In theory, you could use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` to get a full serialized version of a model, this might even be faster depending on where JSON is implemented in the browser.

Comment: @muistooshort aren't you overthinking it? The `toJSON` version of Backbone isn't about stringifying and parsing, but simply returning the set of attributes. Maybe I'm missing something but...

Comment: Maybe. The `toJSON` name was chosen by Backbone because `JSON.stringify` will use the method when serializing things to JSON so `JSON.stringify(some_model)` will call `some_model.toJSON()`. So, if you're calling `m.toJSON()` to produce data for `JSON.stringify` then `toJSON` will be called on anything inside `m`'s attributes so Backbone doesn't have to. If you're calling `toJSON` to prepare data for a view, you're on your own. This is another unfortunate problem of using `toJSON` for two wholly different purposes. At least that's my thinking.

Comment: so far you are using lodash/underscore for cloning, nothing actually  prevents  you from using it for looping in hash as well.

Answer (score 5):

Calling `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(model))` parses the model with all the sub-models and sub-collections recursively. Tried on Backbone version 1.2.3.

Comment: As of Chrome 49, I'd highly recommend against this approach as it appears that now, this would give you 

`{attributes:{ ... },changed:{ ... }}`

Comment: Works perfectly in Chrome 63. This is the simplest solution I've come accross.