# Backbone model with collection property - toJSON method not converting collection to JSON

Tags: backbone.js

So I have a model that has a collection of another model as one of its properties. When using `model.toJSON()`, the collection stays as a collection and isn't converted into an array.

It comes back as something like

```
{
  prop1: "value",
  prop2: "value",
  collection: backbonecollectionobject
  otherprop: "value"
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make Backbones toJSON function include sub-models and collections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17050022/how-to-make-backbones-tojson-function-include-sub-models-and-collections)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the toJSON function by doing something like this:

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.toJSON = function() {
  var json = _.clone(this.attributes);
  for(var attr in json) {
    if(json[attr] instanceof Backbone.Collection) {
      json[attr] = json[attr].toJSON();   
    }
  }
  return json;
};
```

It looks for any attributes with values that are a collection, and converts those toJSON().