# Rendering backbone submodel in handlebars template

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, handlebars.js, backbone-model

I have model and submodel:

```
var Field = Backbone.Model.extend();
var MetaField = Backbone.Model.extend();

var metaField = new MetaField({ title: 'width' });
var field = new Field({ meta: metaField, value: 5});
```

and I want to render this model via handlebars template(view code is ommited)

Template looks like this :

`field: {{ meta.get('title') }} value: {{ value }`}

But meta.get causes an error(as I understand there is no ability to call methods in handlebars). How can I render meta attributes? Should I throw MetaField object to template context?

Comment: What's the error saying? How are you passing both models to the view?

Comment: The problem is that the toJSON() function doesn't recursively go over sub-models. You'll have to implement that behavior; This will help :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17050022/how-to-make-backbones-tojson-function-include-sub-models-and-collections Then you can just access it like so: {{ meta.title }}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to ways of solving this, either in your model on your view, depending on the method you choose it'll change the scope of your change.

### 1. In your Model

*this will always included your meta object in serialized Field object. It'll be used when sending the model to the server or when being rendered in any view.*

```
var Field = Backbone.Model.extend({
   toJSON : function(){
     var json = _.clone(this.attributes);
     if(this.get('meta'){
        json.meta = this.get('meta').toJSON();
     }
     return json;
   }
});
```

### 2. In your view

*This will only apply to the view and will not effect how the model is rendered by other views or sent to server*

```
 var FieldView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  
    //return value of this function is merged with the data
    //that is passed to your template
    templateHelpers: function(){
       return {
          meta: this.model.get('meta').toJSON();
       }
    }

 });
```

#### Template

You can use the `meta` attributes in your template like this,

`field: {{ meta.title }} value: {{ value }}`